# How to store data in a single file and call it in view file?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I have some code that i keep rewriting on different pages on my site so i keep re writing the code over and over on each view file.

I would like to know how i can change the below code so that i can have the below code in only one file. Is it possible to call this file in view file ?

```
if ($model->type == 1) {
    $title = __('Sports');
    $icon_activity = 'icon_set_2_icon-117';
}
if ($model->type == 2) {
    $title = __('Cooking lesson');
    $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-14';
}
if ($model->type == 3) {
    $title = __('Guided tour');
    $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-30';
}
if ($model->type == 4) {
    $title = __('Language conversation');
    $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-20';
}
```

Comment: you can write it any model or use a `beforeAction` function in `controller.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing logic in the view file is not a good practice. Instead, you can make a class and call it in the controller's action. For example, I make this class:
**Tools.php**:

```
<?php
class Tools{
    public function initialize($type){
         $title = "";
         $icon_activity = "";
         if ($type == 1) {
             $title = __('Sports');
             $icon_activity = 'icon_set_2_icon-117';
         }
         if ($type == 2) {
             $title = __('Cooking lesson');
             $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-14';
         }
         if ($type == 3) {
            $title = __('Guided tour');
            $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-30';
         }
         if ($type == 4) {
            $title = __('Language conversation');
            $icon_activity = 'icon_set_1_icon-20';
         }

        return array("title"=>$title, "icon_activity"=>$icon_activity);

    }
}
```

Now, in your action you can do this:

```
public function actionTest(){
      ...
      $tools = new Tools();
      $result = $tools->initialize($model->type)
      $this->render("yourViewName", array(
            "title" => $result['title'],
            "icon_activity" => $result['icon_activity']
      ));
}
```

Finally, you can use `$title` and `$icon_activity` in your view page.